# find specific td background color

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table row with 5 td's.

I'm clicking the second td in the row. I'm getting the background color of that and comparing it to the background color of other td's in the same row.

I want to compare against the 4th td in the row. When I do...

```
    console.log($(this).eq(3).css("background-color"));
```

I get "undefined"

When I do

```
    console.log($(this).next().next().css("background-color"));
```

It returns the color.

So how can I access the 4th td in the row specifically?

Thanks

edit: html as below

```
        <table id="table-fixtures" class="table table-condensed table-fixtures">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="5">UPCOMING</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 
            <tr>
                <td><small>07-01-2014</small></td>
                <td class="team">Alice</td>
                <td><strong>v</strong></td>
                <td class="team">Bob</td>
                <td><small>12:00</small></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>        
                <td><small>07-01-2014</small></td>
                <td class="team">Eve</td>
                <td><strong>v</strong></td>
                <td class"team">George</td>
                <td><small>12:00</small></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

edit:

jquery function:

```
    $('td.team').click( function() {

         if ($(this).css("background-color") == clickColor) {
             console.log($(this).eq(3).css("background-color"));
             console.log($(this).next().next().css("background-color"));
         }
    });
```

Comment: is there a reason that you can't assign a `class` or `id` to the row, so that you can access it directly?

Comment: im building the table dynamically and the number of rows will change. if i assign a row or td an id, wont it be the same id on every row and therefore none specific to that 'cell'?

Comment: You can add a dynamic id too!

Comment: ok, thats interesting. but is there a way to do it using .eq()?

Comment: what is the click JQuery that you are using ? Show full line

Comment: question updated with html and jquery...

Comment: Since you are adding elements dynamically you should use `.on('click',function(){});`

Comment: so use the on('click,....) and eq(3)?

Comment: yes use `on("click,....)` and `eq(3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `this` refer to only one element (the clicked) so eq will not extract anything because it's:

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .eq()
>   method constructs a new jQuery object from one element within that
>   set. The supplied index identifies the position of this element in the
>   set.

since you want to get the element or one of its siblings you can use [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) and to add the previous element use [`addBack`](http://api.jquery.com/addback/) and on them use `eq`

Code:

```
console.log($(this).siblings().addBack().eq(3).css("background-color"));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Yr8an/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, although I don't use jQuery, more details in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K8XuJ/).

```
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('#table-fixtures tbody tr');

for (var i = 0, length = rows.length; i < length; i++) {
    var col = rows[i].querySelector('td:nth-of-type(4)');
    alert(window.getComputedStyle(col).backgroundColor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `$(this)` represents your **one** td element which is just **ONE** element.so **$(this).eq(3)** returning undefined.Because there is no such element.See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Instead you can use:

```
console.log($("td.team").eq(3).css("background-color"))
```